# When i enter q it closes the program?

Tags: c++, arrays

I think I did this right but I don't understand why the program just closes down when i enter `q`. I'm fairly new to programming in general (not just c++) and would be very grateful for some help. This is a project I have on the Array section and I'm kind of falling behind in my class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


void    inputData();
void    displayPlayerData();
void    calculateAverageScore();
void    displayBelowAverage();


const int ARRAY_SIZE = 100;


string  m_playerNames[ARRAY_SIZE];
string  m_playerScores[ARRAY_SIZE];
int m_currentPlayer = 0;
int m_totalScore = 0;
int m_totalPlayers = 0;
double  m_averageScore = 0; 

int main()
{

inputData();
displayPlayerData();
calculateAverageScore();
displayBelowAverage();

return 0;
cin.ignore();
cin.get();
}

void inputData()
{
m_currentPlayer = 0;
while (m_currentPlayer < ARRAY_SIZE)    
{

    cout << "Enter Player Name (Q to quit)" << endl;
    cin >> m_playerNames[m_currentPlayer];


    if ((m_playerNames[m_currentPlayer] == "Q") || (m_playerNames[m_currentPlayer] == "q"))
    {
        break;
    }


    cout << "Enter Player Score" << endl;
    cin >> m_playerScores[m_currentPlayer];


    m_currentPlayer++;
}

m_totalPlayers = m_currentPlayer;
}

void displayPlayerData()
    {

m_currentPlayer = 0;

cout << endl << "Players Summary:" << endl;

while (m_currentPlayer < m_totalPlayers)
{
    cout << m_playerNames[m_currentPlayer] << ":  " << m_playerScores[m_currentPlayer] << endl;
    m_currentPlayer++;
}


}


void calculateAverageScore()
  {

m_currentPlayer = 0;

m_totalScore = 0;


while (m_currentPlayer < m_totalPlayers)
    {
    m_totalScore += atoi(m_playerScores[m_currentPlayer].c_str());


    m_currentPlayer++;
}
m_averageScore = m_totalScore / m_totalPlayers;


cout << endl << "Average score is " << m_averageScore << endl;
}


void displayBelowAverage()
{
m_currentPlayer = 0;

cout << endl << "Players not reaching average:" << endl;
while (m_currentPlayer <= m_totalPlayers)
{
    if (atof(m_playerScores[m_currentPlayer].c_str()) < m_averageScore)
    {
        cout << m_playerNames[m_currentPlayer] << ":  " << m_playerScores[m_currentPlayer] << endl;
    }
    m_currentPlayer++;
}
}
```

Comment: Feel free to accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, you meant to halt the program with

```
cin.ignore();
cin.get();
```

so you could read the output. But you wrote that after the `return` statement, so what does it do? Your program ends, when you `return` from `main`. Make `return 0;` the last statement in `main`.

Comment: so those cin's go before the return?

Comment: Yes, otherwise they won't be called and won't halt the program.

Comment: Oh wow that worked but now i have a follow up question... On the output it lists q as one of the players that fell below the average (q was meant to quit) how could i go about fixing that

Comment: You are unconditionally reading from `cin` to your array. Don't do that. Read to an intermediate variable, then, based on its value, decide whether you want to copy that variable into the array, or you want to stop asking for input.

Answer (score 1):

These lines

```
if ((m_playerNames[m_currentPlayer] == "Q") || (m_playerNames[m_currentPlayer] == "q"))
    {
        break;
    }
```

Mean that a `Q` or `q` will exit the `while` loop in `inputData()`. When that happens, `inputData()` ends and control returns to `main()`. But then the program dies before requesting more input, because you have dead code in `main()`:

```
displayPlayerData();
calculateAverageScore();
displayBelowAverage();

return 0; // returns 0 and exits the program
cin.ignore(); // never runs
cin.get(); // never runs
```

Try reversing those last three lines of `main()`:

```
cin.ignore();
cin.get();
return 0;
```